# How to output data stored in a class/switch case from another case?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a console program for a beginners C# class and I'm totally stuck.
The menu in the program is supposed to be handled with a `switch()` where you input data in `case 1` and you can then request it written out in `case 3`.
The data is stored by calling a constructor in the  class `playback` or `live` , my question is how do I get the stored data written out by choosing `case 3` ?
This is my whole code:

```
class Live
{
    public string name;
    public string instrument;

    public Live(string name, string instrument)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.instrument = instrument;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (string.Format("{0}{1}", name, instrument));
    }

    //default constructor for the constructor in Playback to work
    public Live()
    { }
}

class Playback : Live
{
    public int duration;

    public Playback(int duration)
    {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (string.Format("{0}{1}", base.ToString(), duration));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("###### Menu: ######");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Add a Live");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Add a Playback");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Write out all objects");
        Console.WriteLine("0. End");
        Console.WriteLine("#################");

        bool exit = false;
        while (!exit)
        {
            int val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (val)
            {

                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Input name: ");
                    string namn = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Input instrument: ");
                    string instru = Console.ReadLine();
                    Live live = new Live(namn, instru);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Input duration: ");
                    string time = Console.ReadLine();
                    int tid = int.Parse(time);
                    Playback playback = new Playback(tid);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine(); //this is where I need to output the results
                    break;

                case 0:
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to keep track of just the last `Live` or `Playback` created or one of both, or multiples of both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your variables outside of the `while` loop so you can access them later on.Currently their scope is limited to the case labels.

Comment: This fixed it, thanks alot! I had tried to declare them outside the `switch` before I posted because I thought something like that could be the problem, but I didn't think about the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be able to add multiple `Live`s and `Playback`s?

The add a list for them outside you while-loop:

```
List<Live> sounds = new List<Live>();
```

Because `Playback` inherits from `Live`, you can add playbacks to this list.

In cases 1 and 2, after you have defined your Live or Playback object, add it to the list:

```
sounds.Add(live); // or sounds.Add(playback);
```

In your case 3 you can loop through the sounds and "play" them:

```
foreach(var sound in sounds)
{
   Console.WriteLine(sound.ToString());
}
```

And by the way, your case 0 could be `exit=true;` instead of `Environment.Exit(0);`.

Comment: Yes your right, and this works like a charm! I was going to tackle this problem when the first problem I had was solved, but now you saved me alot of time so thanks alot!